# Log exception to a third party service like Sentry or Rollbar?

Tags: error-message

Are their any best practices?

Maybe some way to hook to craft native exception / log handler with a third party implantation so I could track my errors on services like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) or [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com)?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Went to look into this and while it's true that Craft doesn't have any explicit events around error handling, Yii already does in the form of [onException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onException-detail) and [onError](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onError-detail).

You can listen for them like so:

```
craft()->onException = array($this, 'myCustomExceptionMethodHandler');
```

and

```
craft()->onError = array($this, 'myCustomErrorMethodHandler');
```

---

Original answer:

Craft currently doesn't have any events around error handling, but it's probably not a bad idea to do so for situations like this.

I've added it to our list.

In the meantime, the only workaround I can think of is pretty sketchy, but a plugin could monitor the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder for `[error]` entries and parse the text for the information it needs.